# Table always placed on the last page

Tags: tables, longtable

```
\begin{table}[h!]
     \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
Class and class & Field    & designation & type &size & observation \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{Member} & m $-$ code  & code of member  & N & 10 & Auto increment\\ 

& m$-$name  & member name &A &20 &\\ 

&m$-$fname & member family name &A &20 &\\ 

& email  & email of member &AN &20 &\\ 

&  m$-$type & member type & A &20 &\\ 

& m$-$grade  & member grade & A &20 &\\ 

 \hline

\multirow{6}{4em}{Report   } &R$-$code & report code &N & 10 &Auto increment
 \\ 
& R$-$date& misconduct date  & D & 8& dd$ \ $ mm$ \ $ yyyy \\ & R$-$hour  &  misconduct hour &H &6 &\\ 

&place & misconduct place &A &20 &\\ 

& cause  & cause of report  &A &50 &\\ 

%&st_name and st_fname  & student name and fname &20 &A &\\ 

%& mb_name and mbfname  & member name and  & 20 &A \\ 


\hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{Decision  } &d$-$code & decision code &N & 10 & \\
 &c$-$code & convocation code &N & 10 & Auto increment
\\
& d$-$date& decision date  & D & 8& dd$ \ $ mm$ \ $ yyyy \\ & d$-$hour  &  decision hour &H &6 &\\ 

&f$-$des & final decision &A &50 &\\ 

& cause  & cause of decision  &A &50 &\\ 
& level  & level of infraction  & N & 2&\\ 
& details & details of decision  &A &50 &\\ 
%&st_name and st_fname  & student name and fname &20 &A &\\ 

%& mb_name and mbfname  & member name and  & 20 &A \\ 

\hline

\multirow{6}{4em}{Convocation} &c$-$code & convocation code &N & 10 & Auto increment
\\ 
& m $-$ code  & code of member  & N & 10 & Auto increment
\\
& c$-$date& convocation date  & D & 8& dd$ \ $ mm$ \ $ yyyy \\ & c$-$hour  &  convocation hour &H &6 &\\ 

&c$-$reason& convocation reason &A &50 &\\ 

%& cause  & cause of desicion  &A &50 &\\ 

%&st_name and st_fname  & student name and fname &20 &A &\\ 

%& mb_name and mbfname  & member name and  & 20 &A \\ 

\hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{ Teacher } & st$-$code &student code &N & 10 & Auto increment
 \\ 
& t $-$name   & teacher name  &20 &A & \\ 
 & t$-$fname & teacher family name&20&  A&\\
 & email  & email of member &AN &20 &\\ 
 &  m$-$type & member type & A &20 &\\


\hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{ Student } & st$-$code &student code &N & 10 & Auto increment
\\ 
&st$-$name    & student name  &20 &A &  \\ 
 &st$-$fname & student family name&20&  A&\\
 & email  & email of member &AN &20 &\\ 
 &  m$-$type & member type & A &20 &\\
  \hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{Department chief } & dch$-$code &department chief  code &N & 10 & \\
 &dch$-$name    & department   chief  name  &20 &A &  \\ 
 &dch$-$fname & department chief  family name&20&  A&\\
 & email  & email of department chief  &AN &20 &\\ 
 &  m$-$type & member type & A &20 &\\
 \hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{Dec$ - $Mem} 
  &d$-$code & decision code &N & 10 &  Auto increment
\\ 
&  &  & &  &\\
 &m$-$code & member code &N & 10 &  Auto increment
\\ 
&   &  &  &  &\\
 \hline
\multirow{6}{4em}{Rep$ - $Mem} 
  &r$-$code & report code &N & 10 &  Auto increment
\\ 
&  &   & & &\\
 &m$-$code & member code &N & 10 & Auto increment
 \\ 
&   &  &  &  &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 \caption{Detailed description of fields}

      \label{tabclass}
      \end{center}
      \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your problem  is that your table is too large. Hence it cannot fit on one page and will be placed at the end (as you remove all other options with `h!`).

Comment: you have used `[!h]`  so the table isn't allowed at top of page (no `t`) or bottom of page (no `b`) or on a page on its own (no `p`) so going to the end of the document is most likely.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't LaTeX always add `t` if `h` is used alone: ``LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.`` I think TeXnician is right, but a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help us to very this suggestion.

Comment: Off-Topic: You should not use `center` environment but `\centering` command in floats like this. See: [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes (but only after it's already been deferred for one page) but that's error recovery not something to rely on.

Comment: You might take a look at the `longtable`-package which allows tables spanning more than one page.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in above comments one of solution can be use of `longtable`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Based on guessing about used document clas, page layout ... :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{} lll cc l @{}}
\caption{Detailed description of fields}
    \label{tabclass}    \\
    \toprule
Class and class 
        & Field     & designation           & type & size   & observation       \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Detailed description of fields (cont.)}                                \\
    \toprule
Class and class
        & Field     & designation           & type & size   & observation       \\
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{continue on the next page}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
Member  & m$-$code  & code of member       & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        & m$-$name  & member name          & A     & 20    &                   \\
        & m$-$fname & member family name   & A     & 20    &                   \\
        & email      & email of member      & AN    & 20    &                   \\
        & m$-$type  & member type          & A     & 20    &                   \\
        & m$-$grade & member grade         & A     & 20    &                   \\
    \midrule
Report  & R$-$code  & report code          & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        & R$-$date  & misconduct date      & D     & 8     & dd/mm/yyyy        \\
        & R$-$hour  & misconduct hour      & H     & 6     &                   \\
        & place      & misconduct place     & A     & 20    &                   \\
        & cause      & cause of report      & A     & 50    &                   \\
%&st_name and st_fname  & student name and fname &20 &A &\\
%& mb_name and mbfname  & member name and  & 20 &A \\
    \midrule
Decision& d$-$code  & decision code        & N     & 10    &                   \\
        & c$-$code  & convocation code     & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        & d$-$date  & decision date        & D     & 8     & dd/mm/yyyy        \\
        & d$-$hour  & decision hour        & H     & 6     &                   \\
        & f$-$des    & final decision       & A     & 50    &                   \\
        & cause      & cause of decision    & A     & 50    &                   \\
        & level      & level of infraction  & N     & 2     &                   \\
        & details    & details of decision  & A     & 50    &                   \\
%&st_name and st_fname  & student name and fname &20 &A &\\
%& mb_name and mbfname  & member name and  & 20 &A \\
    \midrule
Convocation
        & c$-$code   & convocation code     & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        & m$-$code   & code of member       & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        & c$-$date   & convocation date     & D     & 8     & dd/mm/yyyy        \\ 
        & c$-$hour   & convocation hour     & H     & 6     &                   \\
        & c$-$reason & convocation reason   & A     & 50    &                   \\
%       & cause      & cause of desicion    & A     & 50    &                   \\
%       & st_name and st_fname  & student name and fname & 20 & A &         \\
%       & mb_name and mbfname   & member name and        & 20 & A &         \\
    \midrule
Teacher & st$-$code  & student code         & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        & t$-$name   & teacher name         & 20    & A     &                   \\
        & t$-$fname  & teacher family name  & 20    & A     &                   \\
        & email      & email of member      & AN    & 20    &   \\
        & m$-$type   & member type          & A     & 20    &   \\
    \midrule
Student & st$-$code  & student code         & N     & 10    & Auto increment    \\
        &st$-$name   & student name         & 20    & A     &   \\
        &st$-$fname  & student family name  & 20    & A     &   \\
        & email      & email of member      & AN    & 20    &   \\
        &  m$-$type  & member type          & A     & 20    &   \\
    \midrule
Department chief 
        & dch$-$code & department chief code & N    & 10    &           \\
        & dch$-$name & department   chief  name         & 20 & A    &   \\
        & dch$-$fname& department chief  family name    & 20 & A    &   \\
        & email      & email of department chief        & AN & 20   &   \\
        &  m$-$type  & member type                      & A  & 20   &   \\
    \midrule
Dec$ - $Mem 
        & d$-$code  & decision code         & N     & 10 &  Auto increment  \\
        &  &  &  &  &\\
        & m$-$code  & member code           & N     & 10 &  Auto increment  \\
        &  &  &  &  &\\
    \midrule
Rep$-$Mem
        &r$-$code   & report code           & N     & 10 &  Auto increment  \\
        &  &  &  &  &\\
        & m$-$code  & member code           & N     & 10 & Auto increment   \\
        &   &  &  &  &\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, thable is redesigned: no vertical rules, for horizontal are used rules from `booktabs` package , no `multirow` cells in the first table column ...